# Adding overload to method of built-in object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

A library I'm working with adds secondary functionality to `JSON.parse`, which is of course a built-in method on a built-in object (but `writable`). I need to add the following overload signature to let the TypeScript compiler know about the new functionality:

```
<T>(text: string, type: { new (): T }) => T
```

Obviously, I would refrain from touching `lib.d.ts`.

I tried redeclaring the entire `JSON` interface, as well as making the global `JSON` variable of that type, but that duplicated all built-in call signatures besides adding the new one.

If I redeclare the `JSON` interface with just the new signature, the whole thing seems to work correctly, the new method overload is accepted along with the built-in ones, but this just seems hackish and fragile:

```
declare interface JSON {
    parse<T>(text: string, type: { new (): T }): T;
}

declare var JSON: JSON;
```

**How do I *correctly* extend a built-in object with a method overload?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `globals.d.ts` and just put in the following :

```
declare interface JSON {
    parse<T>(text: string, type: { new (): T }): T;
}
```

Now you can use this `JSON.parse` overload in `yourfile.ts`.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html